# Combine date and time from string and convert to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

I have 2 strings (date(13/04/2021),time("06:30")) and I want to combine them together to datetime format and I am getting the below error.

System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

What I am doing wrong?

if I change the tempdate format to "yyyy-dd-MM" I get the error there

```
 var type = form["GymType"];
            var time = form["states_ddl"];
            var date = form["date2"];
            var username = form["username"];
            var numberofpersons = 0;
            if (type == "2")
            {
                //gym
                numberofpersons = 9;
            }
            else
            {
                //cross
                numberofpersons = 5;
            }

            Booking toadd = new Booking();
            var currenduser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var tempdate = DateTime.ParseExact(date , "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(tempdate + " " + time, "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the error as text and a sample failing input (again as text).

Comment: @marios post both the code and exception as *text*, not screenshots. You can easily copy the exception message by clicking on `Copy Details`

Comment: Where do those dates come from? If you use a date picker component or even the HTML [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#using_date_inputs) with `type=date` or `type=datetime` you'd get an ISO date, not a localized string. You shouldn't have to parse localized date literals. In fact, you shouldn't even have to read raw data from the form. You should use an strongly-typed object with properties that match the form fields and let ASP.NET MVC do the parsing

Comment: Why are you using FormCollection instead of [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0) ?

Comment: Post all the code as text. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and the important code isn't visible. You have a problem X, how to pass form data to an action and assume Y is the solution, read the raw form data and parse it. When that fails, you asked about Y, not the real problem, X. The real solution is to use ASP.NET MVC model binding with `input type='datetime` or separate `input type='date'` and `input type='time'` form elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is convert de string to a dateTime 'tempdate', and than on the next line you convert it back to a string.
What i would do is convert the date as you do and parse the time separate, than add them together.

```
    var tempdate = DateTime.ParseExact(date , "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var timspan = TimeSpan.Parse(time);
    DateTime d = tempdate.Add(timspan);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convert to do this

```
var date = Convert.ToDateTime("13/04/2021 06:30");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string d = "13/04/2021";
string t = "10:30PM";
string dateAndTime = d.Trim() + ' ' + t.Trim();
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAndTime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt", 
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
dt = DateTime.Parse(dateAndTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
     DateTimeStyles.None);
```